# impossible to change the model to detect

Tags: object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I use the tensorflow lite detector for android. I want to change the model to recognise dog for example, i put my dog.tflite file and his label in assets and change in the code the files to choose (the dog.tflite and his label), change the "TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE=300" to "TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE=224" and "TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED = true;" to "TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED = false;" in the DetectorActivity.java. But i have the error : "Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 25] and a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4].". 
How to fix this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your TF Lite model an "Image Classification" model, or an "Object Detection" model?

> TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 25]

From the model output's shape, I believe that it is an image classification model. You should use this [sample code](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification) instead of the object_detection sample.

Comment: I have a project like this but i want to "export" my model from "Image Classification" to a "Object Detection". Do you know how to make a Object Detection model with folders that contain images ?